# Magento Installation Wizard screen after installing SUPEE-5994 patch

Tags: patches

After installing the SUPEE-5994 patch, (http://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-5994-without-ssh/) I get redirected to \downloader\ with the Magento Installation Wizard screen.

What do I do now?

Comment: didnt you took any backup before performing this update?

Comment: yes I did... I could upload the old files again, but then I still need to apply the patch.

Comment: does this patch reccmended for magento??

Comment: i think SUPEE 5344 and SUPEE 1533 are recommnded

Comment: Yes, but I installed those last week.

Comment: clear the cache once

Comment: The backend also redirects to /downloader

Comment: Which patch you are applying ? Means which version of magento ?

Comment: The 1.9.1 patch, I have a 1.9.1 installation. I now restored the backup. Will try again later. No clue why the installation does not work.

Comment: Did you find a solution eventually?

Comment: It seemed there was a conflict somewhere and some files of a slightly older Magento version, I had someone reinstall Magento and do the update. So now it works, but not sure what exactly the problem was.